# React doesn't set cookies but Postman does?

Tags: reactjs, spring, cookies, axios, postman

I have a spring boot backend that allows a user to login.

When I use postman to send a json payload to login in a user it returns the correct response with a cookie for a JSESSION.

[Postman details with response and cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNCLM.png)

When I send the payload in react (axios) I don't see the cookie for the JSESSION anywhere but the response is still okay ?

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";


login(uniqueId: string, password: string) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "login", JSON.stringify({
            "uniqueId": uniqueId,
            "password": password
        }), 
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'withCredentials': 'true'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            return error.response
    });
}
```

[Chrome tab with response and no cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHthO.png)

Comment: I think cookie is not related React or Axios. When server sent 'Set-Cookie' header, browser need to save to itself. Did you look at DevTools (F12) -> Application -> Cookies?

Edit: Sorry, you posted cookie page, i didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'withCredentials': 'true'` shoud be outside of `headers`  ([Request Config documentstion](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config))

In your case it would be:

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/auth/";


login(uniqueId: string, password: string) {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "login", JSON.stringify({
            "uniqueId": uniqueId,
            "password": password
        }), 
        {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            return error.response
    });
}
```

another solution is create instance axios with parametr `withCredentials: true`  ([creating axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance)).

```
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/";
const api = axios.create({
baseURL: BASE_URL,
withCredentials: true,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

and then you can do:

```
 return api.post("/auth/login", JSON.stringify({
            "uniqueId": uniqueId,
            "password": password
        })) .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            return error.response
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue as mentioned, And I am also using `withCredentials: true` outside the header.

But still, Postman get Cookies And React App not.

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the author's question seeing as you haven't yet provided a solution.